# Changing variable in numerical solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I solved numerically the differential equation:

```
α = 0.4
s = NDSolve[{(1 - y^2)^2/(2 y)*f''[y] == 
    2 *(f[y]^3 - f[y]) - α*f[y]*(1 - y)^2, 
   f[-0.9] == Sqrt[1 + 2 α], f[0.9] == 1}, f, {y, -0.9, 0.9}]
Plot[Evaluate[f[x] /. s], {x, -0.9, 0.9}, PlotRange -> All]
Clear[α, s]
```

I got a solution as an interpolating function of $y$ and I need to recover original variable $x=ArcTanh(y)$, how to replot my solution in terms of $x$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: FYI, for tips & links to useful tools for making things look nice on the site, see http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584

Comment: Isn't `f[Tanh[x]]` the function you want? (Apply `... /. s` as appropriate, of course.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 ty! I just did `Plot[Evaluate[f[Tanh[x]] /. s], {x, ArcTanh[-0.9], ArcTanh[0.9]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]` and it works. Much simpler I thought!

Comment: You're welcome. :)